# Search Bar index case sensitive

Tags: uitableview, swift2, xcode7, uisearchbar

the Index of a tableview search bar is showing upper and lower case letters separated the Upper alphabet first and the lower alphabet starting after, how can I stop this? I need a Index with no case sensitive. The database has upper and lower case words.

// Get the section titles from the dictionary's keys and sort them in ascending order
    sectionTitles = String
    sectionTitles = sectionTitles.sort({ $0 < $1 })
}

Comment: how are you filtering the list ? Show some code ..

Comment: @CW0007007 Added the code for your reference. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting of the dictionary keys, you can append `.lowercaseString` to each key. This will make no difference between upper or lower case letters in your keys, as all keys---in the comparison for sorting---will be lower case strings.

```
func createCockpitDict(){

    // ...

    sectionTitles = [String](cockpitDict.keys)
    sectionTitles = sectionTitles.sort({ $0.lowercaseString < $1.lowercaseString })
}
```

Comment: thanks I will try as soon as I have my computer at home.